# how to generate the below html dynamically and how to populate the corresponding calculated fields on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my html I want to generate it automatically based on number of rows return by a jqgrid. and I want to calculate the values of other input box on change of the other. Please see the jsfiddle link for what I have tried

```
<div class="col-2">
        <div class="filters padd10">
            <div class="formItem" style="border-right:1px solid #4b4b4b; width:29%;">
                <label>New Allocated Amount</label> <span class="formlist"><input type="text" value=""></span>
     <span class="formlist"><input type="text" value=""></span>
     <span class="formlist"><input type="text" value=""></span>
     <span class="formlist"><input type="text" value=""></span>
                <br> <span class="fright mr30">$0</span>

            </div>
            <div class="formItem" style="width:43%; border-right:1px solid #4b4b4b;">
                <label>New Allocated Amount</label> <span class="formlist"><input type="text" value="" class="mr10" ><span class="txtAmount">(or) </span>
                <input type="text" value="" style="width:30px">%</span> <span class="formlist"><input type="text" value="" class="mr10" ><span class="txtAmount">(or) </span>
                <input type="text" value="" style="width:30px">%</span> <span class="formlist"><input type="text" value="" class="mr10" ><span class="txtAmount">(or) </span>
                <input type="text" value="" style="width:30px">%</span> <span class="formlist"><input type="text" value="" class="mr10" ><span class="txtAmount">(or) </span>
                <input type="text" value="" style="width:30px">%</span> <span class="fright" style="margin-right:100px;">$0</span>

            </div>
            <div class="formItem" style="width:12%; margin-right:0px">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="">Freeze</label> <span class="formlist mtop5"><input type="checkbox" value=""></span>
     <span class="formlist mtop5"><input type="checkbox" value=""></span>
     <span class="formlist mtop5"><input type="checkbox" value=""></span>
     <span class=""><input type="checkbox" value=""></span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please see
http://jsfiddle.net/blackeyes123/Dd9Kf/

Comment: For the love of the developers you're asking to help you, replace your alert() calls with console.log() calls.

Comment: Thanks Brian, just replace all the alerts.